# redirect from subfolder to main folder and multiple pages to one page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have a new website, build in WordPress. It will be replacing the old website, which was build on a custom CMS.

The old site is using this structure > domain.nl/content/page-title for most of the content pages. On the new site we will be using domain.nl/page-title.
We also combined a couple of very short content pages into 1. e.g. domain.nl/pageaboutsubject1 and domain.nl/pageaboutsubject2 are now on domain.nl/pageboutboth

The issue with the folder I can resolve by using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will get all the urls redirected without /content/ in betweeen the main folder and the page title.

But now I'm stuck on redirecting the other pages to the new ones.
I read somewere that the 'L' in [R=301,L] prevents further redirects, so I tried to remove that. But no luck.
Adding:

```
RewriteRule ^content/subject1 /subjectboth [R=301]
```

Will not work, and:

```
RewriteRule ^/subject1 /subjectboth [R=301]
```

Will not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be in your reegx for matching 2nd rule.

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on

# match /subject1 or /subject2 and redirect them to /subjectboth
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/kb [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)(subject1|subject2) /subjectboth [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# otherwise remove /content/ from start of URLs
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you explain to me what each part does, for future projects, so I can do this myself next time?

Comment: `RewriteRule (^|/)(subject1|subject2) /subjectboth [R=301,L,NC,NE]` 
I just noticed one of our KB items being redirected as well.
this comes from a link like domain.nl/kb/subject1-solution so were part of the url matches the subjects in the rewrite rule. Can we add something to add an exception for /kb/ or that it has to completely match it? In the two links you send I could not find any reverence to exceptions or exclude.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: And if we have multiple line like these: `RewriteRule (^|/)(subject1|subject2) /subjectboth [R=301,L,NC,NE]` With different subject going to different pages. Do we add the RewriteCond above each RewriteRule or just once above?

Comment: `RewriteRule (^|/)(subject1|subject2) /subjectboth [R=301,L,NC,NE]
`RewriteRule (^|/)(subject3|subject4) /subjectboth2 [R=301,L,NC,NE]`

Comment: mmm. can't edit the comment above. I was trying to write that we used 2 rules like that under each other.

Comment: It does, but not the exception to /kb/ but that might have been cache as I got different results in Firefox and Safari. But the condition at the top and then the rewrites underneath should work you say?

Comment: The strange thing is, that it is still not working for the /kb/subject link. 
This will still redirect to the information page.

I asked someone else to check the page on a different computer.  I cleared the WordPress cache before.

Comment: try my updated answer again after clearing your browser cache.